# Does changing the version of hibernate couse this error? how to solve it?

Tags: spring, hibernate, migration

We are creating a new Spring Boot application that we are using to migrate the version 1 to 3. But after adding the dependency and making certain modification we are getting an error

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.hibernate.search.cfg.impl.SearchConfigurationFromHibernateCore.<init>(SearchConfigurationFromHibernateCore.java:96)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
'org.hibernate.MultiTenancyStrategy org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryOptions.getMultiTenancyStrategy()'
```

The calling method's class, org.hibernate.search.cfg.impl.SearchConfigurationFromHibernateCore, was loaded from the following location:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/<myname>/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-search-orm/5.11.12.Final/hibernate-search-orm-5.11.12.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/search/cfg/impl/SearchConfigurationFromHibernateCore.class
```

The called method's class, org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryOptions, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/<myname>/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.4.4.Final/hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions.class
jar:file:/C:/Users/<myname>/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.33.Final/hibernate-core-5.4.33.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions.class
```

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryOptions: file:/C:/Users/<myname>/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.4.4.Final/hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.hibernate.search.cfg.impl.SearchConfigurationFromHibernateCore and org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryOptions

We have cleared tegh .m2 folder already but no use. Can you please help